# Traversing down and sideways in the DOM

Tags: javascript

I have the following structure:

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggleThis(this); return false;">
   <div style="width:100%;">
     <h3 style="display:inline-block"><img src="/assets/images/plus_qty.png" class="faqPlusMinus">Where is my order?</h3>
   </div>
</a>
```

I'm trying to alert the `src` of the image tag but get the following error:

```
TypeError: e.firstChild.firstChild is null
```

Here's the code:

```
function toggleThis(e){
    var elc = e.firstChild.firstChild.nextSibling;
    alert(elc.src);/
}
```

I'm NOT using JQuery.

Comment: That `<img>` isn't a sibling of `<h3>`, but a child. Try `e.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild`.

Comment: `firstChild` will return text nodes (including blank ones), which obviously don't have any children of their own. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.firstChild. You may want `children[0]` instead.

Comment: Why not `e.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want

```
e.children[0].children[0].children[0]
```

To retrieve the first Element child (the div), then its first Element child (`h3`), then its first Element child (the `img`).

However, it may be easier to just say

```
e.querySelector('img')
```

That will also be less brittle when the HTML changes for any reason.

Answer (score 3):

Check the type of `.firstChild`, it's probably a `TextNode` corresponding to the white space between tags, rather than the `div` tag. `TextNode`s don't have a `firstChild`.

You said you aren't using jQuery, but maybe you can use [`element.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.querySelector). This would let you write the function in such a way that can still work even when someone adds or removes some nodes in your HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Since `firstChild` is TextNode in your case you can't access `img` element. Instead you have several options. First of all you can use `firstElementChild`:

```
function toggleThis(e){
    var elc = e.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.firstElementChild;
    alert(elc.src);
}
```

Then you can use `children` collection:

```
function toggleThis(e){
    var elc = e.children[0].children[0].children[0];
    alert(elc.src);
}
```

```js
function toggleThis(e){
    var elc = e.children[0].children[0].children[0];
    alert(elc.src);
  
    // .. or
    var elc = e.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.firstElementChild;
    alert(elc.src)
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="toggleThis(this); return false;">
   <div style="width:100%;">
       <h3 style="display:inline-block"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" class="faqPlusMinus">Where is my order?</h3>
   </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `firstChild` is a text node with aline break, you could see this by doing `console.log(e.firstChild)`.

So you need to move on to the next sibling. This works but is nasty

```js
function toggleThis(e){
  var elc = e.firstChild.nextSibling.firstChild.nextSibling.firstChild;
  console.log(elc.src);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="toggleThis(this); return false;">
   <div style="width:100%;">
     <h3 style="display:inline-block"><img src="/assets/images/plus_qty.png" class="faqPlusMinus">Where is my order?</h3>
   </div>
</a>
```

Better to do this:

```js
function toggleThis(e){
  var elc = e.querySelector('div h3 img');
  console.log(elc.src)
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="toggleThis(this); return false;">
       <div style="width:100%;">
         <h3 style="display:inline-block"><img src="/assets/images/plus_qty.png" class="faqPlusMinus">Where is my order?</h3>
       </div>
    </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to hustle with all that firstChild? Why not just getElementsByTagName, or add a class and select by it?

```js
function toggleThis(e){
  var elc = e.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
  console.log(elc.src);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="toggleThis(this); return false;">
   <div style="width:100%;">
     <h3 style="display:inline-block"><img src="/assets/images/plus_qty.png" class="faqPlusMinus">Where is my order?</h3>
   </div>
</a>
```